# Pyspark : Getting error py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o6604.save.\n: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark

I am running a pyspark script from NiFi to load data in postgresql. I keep getting this error for some of the files -

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o6604.save.\n: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I tried adding the configuration for offheap like below -

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.memory.offHeap.enabled","true").config("spark.memory.offHeap.size","16g").appName("test_app").getOrCreate()
```

But it did not help. Any other way to resolve this error?

Comment: not enough information to answer. First you need to mention how are you doing your spark-submit with what all options like xms xmx number of executors, cores. Also how are you repartitioning the data these are factors you need to adjust and see. enabling "spark.memory.offHeap.enabled" wont do any magic.

Comment: Pyspark is submitted thru the NiFi processor executesparkinteractive. I have this line of code in script. Where I am creating a list from all the column values of pyspark df. df has 10000 rows. Is it responsible for causing the memory error - column_list = customer_df.select('id').collect()

Comment: collect() is the culprit you are moving all your data in to driver by doing this, think alternatives to this

Comment: I changed this to column_list = list(customer_df.select('id').toPandas()['id']) Still getting the error